# Software adjustement of LCD monitor brightness in Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, robotics, debian-based

Is there any way of changing the `gamma/contrast/brightness` of monitor in Raspberry?

My Samsung 960BF doesn't have any hardware adjustment.

I tried using xbacklight and got error "No outputs have backlight property".

Gddccontrol also didn't work. Error:

```
"I/O warning: failed to load external entity "/home/pi/.dccontrol/monitorlist"  
   Document not parsed successfully
   Probing for available monitors"
```

And nothing is happening.

I connected my monitor through DVI-HDMI cable. Maybe this is why it doesn't work?

I'm using `Raspberry Pi B+ V1.2 with Raspbian`.

Comment: This is ot for [so], which is about programming. Please migrate your question to [su] or [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @umläute  Ok, thank you for that notice. I didn't know that this question doesn't suit here.